# Delphi Screen Dimensions with Fonts > 100% vs Actual Resolution

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts

In Windows 10, Delphi XE7, when font size is set to > 100%, Delphi's screen[0].workarea.rect returns dimensions that reflect the font scaling. E.G., with the graphics card for screen 0 set to 1920x1080, screen[0].workarea.rect.width returns 1280 (assuming there is no vertical task bar, etc.). However, I can't find a way to programatically determine that the width is being returned as 1280 due to the font scaling vs. 1280 being the actual graphics card setting. Can anyone tell me how to do 1 or more of the following -- any 1 of them would give me the info I need to differentiate among the possibilities: 1) determine what the font percentage is; 2) determine what the hardware resolution is.

Comment: Stop having dpi virtualization and you don't need to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

[GetDeviceCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx) function returns a parameter, defined by index, of chosen device context.

Works in Windows 7, gives true font size value for my desktop (96 dpi is default value "small font 100%")

```
  dc := GetDC(0);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('hor res %d', [GetDeviceCaps(dc, HORZRES)]));
  lp := GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSX);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('logx %d percents %d%%', [lp, 100 * lp div 96]));

  hor res 1280
  logx 120 percents 125%
```

Comment: And what if dpi virtualization is active?

Comment: @David Heffernan  Author's 1280/1920 confusion - is it evidence of dpi virtualization?

Comment: So screen resolution part of my answer is not actual for that situation. And I doubt what is 'true' font percent value (if any exists...)